# Wordpress site transaltion - Serious difficulties in translating strings

Tags: wordpress, translation

I have no great experience and I am having great difficulty in translating a portal in wordpress.
Some strings are untranslatable despite all the tests made:

1. Translate the theme directly with Loco Translate, after searching for all the matches of the string in the various .po files in the folders
2. Force translation in functions.php

```
    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');
    
    function translate_text($translated) { 
      $translated = str_ireplace('mystring', 'mystrintraslated', $translated); 
      return $translated; 
    }
```

3. Modify all occurrences of the source, to see if the change affected the site:

```
    public function single_dummy_post() {
        bp_theme_compat_reset_post(
            array(
                'ID'             => 0,
                'post_title'     => __( 'mystringtranslated', 'mytheme),
                'post_author'    => 0,
                'post_date'      => 0,
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_type'      => 'page',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'is_page'        => true,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
            )
        );
    }
```

also clearing the cache after the changes.

Nothing to do, the site remains unchanged.
What can I still try to do?

Comment: It's rare but some text is generated by the javascript (for example, on a form usually date pickers work this way). You can't translate them with the methods above. For all others usually I prefer your 2nd method `gettext, ngettext`

Comment: if it were as you say, I should find the string "mystring" in the search (*. *) among the folders / subfolders, but it is not.
Could the string be in the database?

Comment: If it is not found in folders, then it might be in the database or could be in the .po (translation file)